# Can't open a connection from a added data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle, connection-string

I have a Oracle Database I want to connect to a VS solution and show in a GridView.

The first thing I did was connect to the database via the Server Explorer.
When I click on it I can see the properties including the connectionstring.

The Second thing I did was add the some database in Data Sources and called it "DataSet1".

Now I've tried a couple of things but they're all variations of this bit of code:

```
private void GetData1()
{
    connectionString = 
    "Data Source=" + dSource + ";User ID=" + userID + ";Password=" + password + ";Unicode=True";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        `         
        `SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);`

        SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter);

        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

        dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    }
}
```

When I copy the exact connectionstring previously mentioned. I get this error:
 "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll"
At the line "`using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))`"

When I change the connectionstring to:
`connectionString =  "Data Source=" + dSource + ";User ID=" + userID + ";Password=" + password;`

(I deleted the `unicode= true` bit)

I get the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

at the line "`connection.Open();`"

I call this method at runtime.

I guess the problem is the connectionstring or the database itself, I'm not sure.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Your question notes you are connecting to an Oracle database, but you are using a `SqlConnection` and other SQL Server specific objects.

Comment: fml you are right. I didn't know i needed to use OracleConnection. Thanks! I'm going to try it out.

Comment: It worked :). Not going to make that mistake ever again